# Why is my web3j wrapper failing to generate?

Tags: solidity, solc, web3j

I've created a smart contract in solidity which I've compiled with solc into a .bin & a .abi file. However, when I run the generator on the .abi and .bin files it returns a JSONParseException citing an unexpected character.
io
This is my smart contract:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

    contract Contract {

      address public creator;


      event Log(uint256 id);


      function Contract() {
        creator = msg.sender;
      }

      function kill() {
        selfdestruct(creator);
      }

      function add(uint256 id) {
        Log(id);
    }
   }
```

Comment: How and what generator do you run?

Answer (score 2):

Just tried your contract. It seems correct and I was able to create a wrapper successfully. Here is what I did:

Put a `ContractName.sol` file wilth you source into `d:\tmp>` then in that directory executed the following from the command line:

```
d:\tmp>solc ContractName.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o .
```

Which generated .abi and .sol files in that same directory. Then:

```
d:\tmp>web3j solidity generate --binFile=Contract.bin --abiFile=Contract.abi -o . -p org.your.package.name
```

Generated me a wrapper under the folloring directoty (according to the package structure provided in command line):

```
d:\tmp\org\your\package\name\Contract.java
```

Everything seems fine, you should be able to create yours. I installed `colc` and `web3j` tools like described here:
    [solc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html),
    [web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
https://remix.ethereum.org/
as IDE. It will tell you exactly where the problem is (curly bracket is missing)